# Conditional raster calculations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I want to create a global map for Evaporation-precipitation (E-P). Evaporation has negative fluxes at some places. If evaporation has negative values, I need to do the operation (E+P) or else for positive values of evaporation (E-P).

Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

It is a single map for evaporation with negative as well as positive values.

Answer (score 5):

Use raster calculator:

```
("Evap@1"<0)*("Evap@1"+"Prec@1") + ("Evap@1">=0)*("Evap@1"-"Prec@1")
```

Which for negative evap values will translate to:

```
1*(Evap + Prec) + 0*(Evap - Prec)
```

[image]